# Spring MVC - @ExceptionHandler based on Accept header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` that intercepts all requests and performs user authorization checks. Very basically:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    User user = ... // get user
    checkIfAuthorized(user); // throws AuthorizationException
    return true;
}
```

I then have an `@ExceptionHandler` for that `AuthorizationException`.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = AuthorizationException.class) 
public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotAuthorized(AuthorizationException e) {
    // TODO Custom EXCEPTION HANDLER for json/jsp/xml/other types, based on content type
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("You are not authorized to access that page.", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

This is fine if the (unauthorized) request accepts `text/plain` (and can be easily changed for json). 
How can I make different `@ExceptionHandler`s for specific `Accept` headers?

`@RequestMapping` has `produces()`. Is there something similar for `@ExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of two approaches:

**Manually**

```
public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotAuthorized(AuthorizationException e, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // TODO Custom EXCEPTION HANDLER for json/jsp/xml/other types, based on content type
    if (/*read header accept from request and build appropiate response*/) {}
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("You are not authorized to access that page.", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    return responseEntity;
```

**Automatically**

```
@ResponseBody
public SomeObject handleNotAuthorized(AuthorizationException e, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // TODO Custom EXCEPTION HANDLER for json/jsp/xml/other types, based on content type
    /* Construct someObject and let Spring MessageConverters transform it to JSON or XML. I don't remember what happens in case of HTML (it should go to a view)*/
    return someObject;
```

Don't forget to set the Response's Status code.

Comment: In the second example, for html, it'll use [RequestToViewNameTranslator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/RequestToViewNameTranslator.html). I kind of don't want a jsp named after the path. With your first example, I wan't to return a view name for `text/html`, is that possible with `ResponseEntity`?

Comment: It looks like ResponseEntity is more oriented to REST responses. You should return a ModelAndView (or only a View) for that case.

Comment: You suggest making the return type simply `Object` and returning whichever based on the header?

Comment: Yes. In this case Spring doesn't care about type safety. It does instanceOf to check what the object is.

Answer (score 3):

I know this comes late but I've been looking up a solution to this, came across this question and found what I think to be a better solution. You can return "forward:/error" in your @ExceptionHandler (returning a String) to forward the request to a

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
ErrorController {...}
```

and use

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "text/html") 
ModelAndView errorPage() {...}
```

on one method of that ErrorController,

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json") // or no 'produces' attribute for a default
MyJsonObject errorJson() {...} on another.
```

I think this is a pretty neat way to do it, it's probably already out there but I didn't find it when trying to look it up.

So basically the @ExceptionHandler is the same for all, but forwards to a controller that can do the usual stuff

Comment: This makes sense and worked in my case.
Before returning "forward:/error" I had to call 
`request.setAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());` (substitute status as necessary) because AbstractErrorController uses that property to determine the status and then maps it to an error page. If I don't set that property it defaults to "200" which obviously I haven't provided an error page for.

Comment: That's correct. I also found out later that you need an additional @ExceptionHandler method in your ErrorController - make sure it doesn't loop by forwarding the request to self in case of an exception during the error controller invocation (ClientAbort for instance can happen regardless of how safe your controller is)

Comment: Thanks, I actually caught a HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException thrown by Spring after returning a response from my ErrorController. This was happening on irregular favicon requests by iOS Firefox (FxiOS).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same use case, but the same requirement. I solve it with a custom HttpMessageConverter implementation.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class MyResource {

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<MyDto> get (@PathVariable(ID) long id)
            throws IOException {

        throw new MyCustomException();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}/export", produces = "application/zip")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> export (@PathVariable(ID) long id)
            throws IOException {

        throw new MyCustomException();
    }
}
```

...

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyCustomExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
    public JsonAPIErrorDocument handleException (MyCustomException e) {

        return ....;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class JsonAPIErrorDocumentToByteArrayMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter {

    public ErrorDocumentToByteArrayMessageConverter () {

        super(new MediaType("application", "zip"), MediaType.ALL);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports (Class clazz) {

        return JsonAPIErrorDocument.class == clazz;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object readInternal (Class clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException,
            HttpMessageNotReadableException {

        return new byte[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal (Object t, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
            throws IOException,
            HttpMessageNotWritableException {

    }
}
```

...

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.foo" })
public class ApplicationConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    ...

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters (List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper));
        converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new JsonAPIErrorDocumentToByteArrayMessageConverter());
    }

    ...
}
```